# ziparchive open method is not working

Tags: php, zip, wampserver, php-ziparchive

i am creating a zip file from an array containing files using a function i made

```
function create_zip($files = array(),$destination = '',$overwrite = false) {
//if the zip file already exists and overwrite is false, return false
if(file_exists($destination) && !$overwrite) { return false; }
    //create the archive
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if($zip->open($destination,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true)    {
            return false;
    }
    //add the files
    foreach($files as $file) {
            $zip->addFile($file);
    }
    //debug
    echo 'The zip archive contains ',$zip->numFiles,' files with a status of ',$zip->status;

    //close the zip -- done!
    $zip->close();

    //check to make sure the file exists
    return file_exists($destination);
}
```

but when i use it with a proper array of files - the destination path is writeable as i create directory in the same path just before creating the zip and it works - it returns 
'The zip archive contains 4 files with a status of 0'
when i check the folder during submitting i see a file called fileName.zip.0156a and it's deleted in few seconds 
and when i tries to get the response of $zip->open it returns 1

Comment: Nothing is strange with this code. Btw why your zip is named `fileName.zip.0156a` (.0156a after .zip). Edit: You haven't a function which cleans your directory ?

Comment: how to clean it 
i dun know why that extension is added to the file i think its temp ?

Comment: Oh. It's not wanted ? Print your `$destination` please.

Comment: C:\wamp\www\cms\uploads\passwords\56_password.zip